# How to read the XML file getting from the web service in ios

Tags: ios, xml, web-services

I want to read some URLs those are coming in xml file through a web service.

```
<chaneels>
    <chaneel name="AAA">
        <url>http://188.138.95.120:8010/</url>
    </chaneel>
    <chaneel name="gold">
        <url>http://188.138.95.120:8020/</url>
    </chaneel>
    <chaneel name="BBB">
        <url>http://188.138.95.120:8090/</url>
    </chaneel>
    <chaneel name="CCC">
        <url>http://188.138.95.120:8050/</url>
    </chaneel>
    <chaneel name="DDD">
        <url>http://209.239.127.105:8010/</url>
    </chaneel>
</chaneels>
```

This is the `XML` I'm getting from the web service. Then I want to get these each of URLs separately. Can anyone tell me a way to do this?

Comment: can u give me any utoril ulr?

Comment: @Divyu: Wrong comment. He needs XML Parsing so he need to use NSXMLParser

Comment: @Divyu JSON Kit can we used for parsing XML ? Strange !

Comment: ooh my mistake. yeah Use XML Parser

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: [MacTech](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.06/XMLParser/index.html),[Parse XML](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

Comment: Tutorial for [parsing XML using GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

First start the parser by checking element `chaneel` where `item`, `currentName`, `currentURL`, `allData` are `property` declared.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
         item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
         currentURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
         [currentName appendString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
}
```

After that retrieve the desire values....

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
     if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"url"]) {
            [currentURL appendString:string];
        }
}
```

After that store the value into a dictionary with desire key in this method...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"]) {
        [item setObject:currentName forKey:@"Name"];
        [item setObject:currentURL forKey:@"URL"];

        [allData addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}
```

In the `allData`, you will get all the URLs corresponding their Name...